# Swing : Focus Components

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have a Frame that contains CardLayout with various JPanels setting it to center of the JFrame.

On 1st Panel, I have focus on 1st component i.e. a button. But can't have focus on other panels or components. While setting the required panel, I use the following code :

```
public void SetMainPanel(String panel) {
    activePanel = panel;
    SetFontSize();
    cards.show(mainPanel, panel);
    mainPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.repaint();
    mainPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mainPanel.grabFocus();
            mainPanel.getComponent(0).requestFocus();
        }
    });
    //mainPanel.getComponent(0).requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

But I can't get focus on the panel or its 1st component. How can I make the setting panel to have focus and focus on its 1st component ? Finally, for focus on each Panel what is better - FocusPolicy, Manager, Keyboard.... Panels either has all buttons OR table and buttons OR form with fields. There are this 3 types of Panels.
BTW, the panels added to cardLayout are focusable.

Any ideas....

EDIT : Code has been edited as shown by mKorbel.

Comment: All panels has setFocusCycleRoot(true); & setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);   FOR panels with a Table and a panel of buttons, how do I transfer the focus from table to panel of buttons ?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to add a ComponentListener to the panel and handle the componentShown() event to place focus on whatever component you want.

Or [Card Layout Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/31/card-layout-focus/) extends the CardLayout to provide this functionality by default.

Comment: @camickr, Card Layout Focus is not helping me. I added ComponentShown event to my mainPanel whose layout is cardPAnel and to other Panel also which am showing. Added grabFocus() & getComponent(0).requestFocusInWindow(); to both the events. But that also doesn't change the status anyway. Infact the componentShown event is never fired at all on any of the panels.

Comment: @TVD, I only suggested the componentShown() might work. If it doesn't, then I gave a second approach which I know does work.

Answer (score 2):

in most of cases (when is Focus_Cycle inside one Container) works for me follows code

```
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mainPanel.getComponent(0).grabFocus();
            mainPanel.getComponent(0).requestFocus();
            // or mainPanel.getComponent(0).requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't use mainPanel.getComponent(0).grabFocus(); - its not available. I can gave mainPanel.grabFocus(); mainPanel.getcomponent(0).requestFocus(). With that I go to press 2 times TAb to have focus on 1st component.

Comment: No problem. I never needed to use `grabFocus()`, always was using `requestFocusInWindow()`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrgg ... should have known that Rob has a nice ready-to-use class for handling the case :-) Adding this nevertheless, to emphasize the basics

The base problem is that focus transfer gets completely confused when the focused component is removed from the hierarchy (as happens when showing a new card). In this case, the transfer has to be handled manually. Rob's solution is sound and basically the same as this. Both trigger the focus transfer by messaging card.transferFocus: the advantage over requestFocus is twofold

- safe if there is no child (or no focusable)
- leaves the timing/queuing issue to be handled by the default mechanism

Here's a code snippet of the bare-bones approach

```
    final CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
    final JComponent main = new JPanel(layout );
    Action action = new AbstractAction("toggle cards") {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            layout.next(main);
            Component visibleChild = main.getComponent(0).isVisible() ?
                    main.getComponent(0) : main.getComponent(1);
            visibleChild.transferFocus();        
        }
    };
    main.getActionMap().put("nextCard", action);
    main.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
       .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"), "nextCard");
    JComponent first = new JPanel();
    first.add(new JTextField(20));
    first.add(new JButton("dummy on first"));

    JComponent second = new JPanel();
    second.add(new JTextField("I'm on the second"));
    second.add(new JButton("me on second, too"));

    main.add(first, "one");
    main.add(second, "two");
```